# PHP Convert string to array and group by value

Tags: php, arrays, string, backend

Im stuck in solving this, given a string like **WWLLWWWLWLLL** I want to group it into array so the output should be

```
[
    0 => 'WW',
    1 => 'LL',
    2 => 'WWW',
    3 => 'L',
    4 => 'W',
    5 => 'LLL',
]
```

Here is what I have started and I'm stuck what's the next step

```
$str = 'WWLLWWWLWLLL';
str_split($str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit messy, but it does the job:

```
$str = 'WWLLWWWLWLLL';
$str = str_split($str);
foreach($str as $k => &$v) {
    $c = 1;
    while(isset($str[$k + $c]) && $str[$k + $c] == $v[0]) {
        $v .= $str[$k + $c];
        unset($str[$k + $c]);
        $c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm sure OP's teacher will give him full marks for your work.